# Visual Studio Online CI Builds and Gated Check ins

Tags: version-control, visual-studio, builds, team-foundation-server

I'm looking for a way to achieve something like this using VS online ...

I have a lot of small solutions in the root of the repo that are structured a bit like ...

```
Foo.sln
   "/Framework/xxx"
   "/Foo/*.csproj"

Bar.sln
   "/Framework/xxx"
   "/Bar/*.csproj"
```

...
There are generally some common pieces in each of the solutions that are shared but each solution also contains the solution specific pieces.

I would like a way to be able to setup a CI build that can determine what solutions the code changes are in and do an appropriate Gated CI build but not build anything else.

Is this possible, if so how?

I have been able to setup a CI build that builds everything no matter what gets checked in but i'm thinking that what I need is some sort of build def that picks "sub builds" to actually run by looking at the files checked in.

Or maybe you guys have a better way to achieve this (maybe using powershell to query the changeset via api or something)?

Comment: Are you having performance problems with lengthy builds?  What is the motivation for a partial build?

Comment: I want check ins to be gated and CI built because my team can't be trusted to not break the repo and the boss seems to think that branching is a bad idea (out of my control) ... it's a means to ensure we are productive and not waiting around for a full build (around 15 mins)

Comment: Is the cure worse than the disease?

Comment: well longer term I would like to turn off the gated check in but it still makes sense to have a CI build, and why CI build everything if only a small part of the repo is affected?

Comment: It's about making sure we don't re-build and deploy stuff that has no changes so we can handle any problems sooner otherwise we have devs sat around for 15 mins (or longer if there's a queue of builds) instead of 1 to 2 mins for the smaller builds. Do you think this is the wrong way to approach the problem? Should I just build everything and push harder for branching, then gate the main branch only?

Comment: I don't have access to my server atm, but there is a setting in the build definition that allows you to filter which directory should be cloned. If you want your solutions to build independently, you'll need to set up a build for each solution, filtered on its own directory. However, I would recommend having the full build run early in the am, again at lunch, and again near the end of the day. That will help catch any cross-project dependencies breaking things outside their own solution.

Comment: The problem is not setting up builds that build a piece of the repo, its determining on check in which build to pick based on what was checked in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok had a discussion with the team and have come to the following conclusions ...

- Branching will be introduced in to TFS
- Gated check ins will be applied to "non working branches"
- CI builds, with gating will build everything and execute all unit tests
- Working branch(es) will CI build but not be gated to give visibility or issues to the dev team

The net result is that I don't need to worry about what's in the check in that just took place nor do I have a time issue with devs / testers being sat around waiting on builds.

After digging around in the MSDN documentation I came to the conclusion that trying to have more granular builds was not reasonably achievable without a lot of work on TFS so this feels like the cleaner approach to achieve the same result.

Comment: More granular builds aren't difficult at all. You just have to specify what directories to build and what directories to monitor for changes. Whether or not doing that is a good idea depends very much on the nature of your code base.